# NLP solution to tag "me" without any login facility

Tags: lucene, nlp

I am working a project which requires apache lucene and nlp to search from a data lake. This is specifically related to only banking domain. The questions asked by users can be like "Show me my account balance from last month?" or "Show me my personal details?". The problem however is there is no login interface so how would I relate this "me" to the person asking the questions? Is there any login facility available or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Mention some research or code here.

Comment: I don't have any code. I am asking for a solution theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing your software, you can build a login interface! With the login credentials, you can search in lucene. You need to extract the key terms, for example, "Show me my personal details", here key terms are "show", "personal details" and then you can search in lucene index with the users' account no. and retrieve the account details.

You actually need some unique information to identify a user, without that you even can't retrieve any information from index!